# Unable to read from remote repository after git mirror

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitolite, mirror

I have been experimenting with creating a mirror of one of my gitolite repositories and have run into a problem. I created the mirror on the same machine as the original git repositories using the commands;

```
cd /var/repo_mirrors
git clone --mirror /home/gitolite/repositories/Test.git
```

( I was essentially following the steps from here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories#Git-repository )

I also wanted to be able to browse the repository so i did a chown to www-data so that Apache could read.

That all worked fine. But the problem now is i'm unable to clone/push the original repository. When i try i get the following error;

> fatal: failed to read object a0d91d1cc22bfbd5666d51c1ea7a5015008e50b6:
>   Permission denied fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

**Note**: before the mirror everything worked OK

Any ideas on what went wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to the hardlinks created during a [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> The files under `.git/objects/` directory are hardlinked to save space when possible.

Try the same clone, but without hardlinks:

```
cd /var/repo_mirrors
git clone --mirror --no-hardlinks /home/gitolite/repositories/Test.git
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. Worrying that a mirror can cause such an issue.

Comment: Thanks dude, just exactly my case: I cloned a local repo, chowned the clone to postgres and ran some SQL scripts. But after that I wasn't able to push anything anymore... And indeed, it turned out, that original object files where owned by postgres too (damn!)... Chowned it back to gitolite and pushing magically was possible again.